# Getting item from Json and writing it with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, nested

I have a problem here. I got this html with nested classes . The problem is that i need to get 3 texts from JSON and make them show in my html in order from 1-3. The best I did is to show only one in all of them. I think i have a problem with parsing but I am not exactly sure. The problem could also be with the "nth-child". I could use any hint or solution .

The "bla" class that you can see is for testing only.

```
<form method="POST" action="#" id="data-form">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="input-personal-info">
                    <div class="info-label">
                        <label class="info-label-class bla" for="name"> 
</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-input">
                        <input id="name" class="info-input-class" type="text" 
name="Name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-personal-info">
                    <div class="info-label">
                        <label class="info-label-class" for="email"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-input">
                        <input id="email" class="info-input-class" 
 type="email" name="Mail" placeholder="Enter your Email" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-personal-info">
                    <div class="info-label">
                        <label class="info-label-class"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-input">
                        <input class="info-input-class" type="number" 
 name="age" placeholder="Age" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the JSON

```
var json ='
{
   "formTitle":"Survey Form",
   "letUsnow":"Let us know how we can improve freeCodeCamp",
   "info":[
      {
         "infoPersonalInfo":[
            {
               "infoLabel":[
                  {
                     "text":"<sup </sup>Name:"
                  },
                  {
                     "text":"<sup>* </sup>Email:"
                  },
                  {
                     "text":"<sup>* </sup>Age:"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "roleOptionsLabel":"Which option best describes your current role?",
   "reccomendLabel":"<sup>* </sup>How likely is that you would recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?",
   "fccLabel":"What do you like most in FCC:",
   "improvedLabel":"Things that should be improved in the future(Check all that apply):",
   "commentsLabel":"Comments or Suggestions?"
}
';
```

And this is the JavaScrpt part

```
var json ='{"formTitle":"Survey Form","letUsnow":"Let us know how we can 
improve freeCodeCamp","info":[{"infoPersonalInfo":[{"infoLabel":[{"text":" 
<sup>* 
</sup>Name:"},{"text":"<sup>* </sup>Email:"},{"text":"<sup>* 
</sup>Age:"}]}]}],"roleOptionsLabel":"Which option best describes your 
current 
role?","reccomendLabel":"<sup>* </sup>How likely is that you would recommend 
freeCodeCamp to a friend?","fccLabel":"What do you like most in 
FCC:","improvedLabel":"Things that should be improved in the future(Check all 
that apply):","commentsLabel":"Comments or Suggestions?"}';

$(document).ready(function(){

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

divTitle(obj);
divForm(obj);
});

function divTitle(obj){

$('.form-title').text(obj.formTitle);
};
function divForm(obj){
$('#paraf').text(obj.letUsnow);

for(i in obj.info){
    for(j in obj.info[i].infoPersonalInfo){
        for(k in obj.info[i].infoPersonalInfo[j].infoLabel){
            var k = parseInt(i) + parseInt(j) + 1 ;
            console.log("k:" + k);

//$('.bla').html(obj.info[i].infoPersonalInfo[j].infoLabel[k].text);
            $('.info-label:nth-child(' + k + ').info-label- 
class').html(obj.info[i].infoPersonalInfo[j].infoLabel[k].text);
        }
    }
};
```

I do not get any console errors and the output is 3 k:1
[image]

Comment: Your `JSON` is malformed. Fix it.

Comment: I you mean in the question , i fixed it now . Still hadn't found the solution .

Comment: `JSON` is still malformed. Make sure that you can copy & paste your exact JSON code into console and it works.

Comment: var k = parseInt(i) + parseInt(j) + 1 ; this is your problem i and j are in this json always 0, and +1 this is the reason you get always  k:1. Keep in mind the counts here start from 0. If you consolelog just k without any calculation you get k:0 k:1 k:2 for the tree text messages

Comment: @SehaxX Ah I see , but why are i and j = 0 ?

Comment: @BojanKolano because you have just one element in first and second array. And the array count starts from zero (0).

Comment: @BojanKolano I suggest you this site to improve your skils in JS: https://javascript.info/

Comment: @SehaxX THanks for the site ! Will check it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. You need to use jQuery:eq to grab the element by index. Also, no need to rewrite "k".

```js
var json = {
   "formTitle":"Survey Form",
   "letUsnow":"Let us know how we can improve freeCodeCamp",
   "info":[
      {
         "infoPersonalInfo":[
            {
               "infoLabel":[
                  {
                     "text":"<sup </sup>Name:"
                  },
                  {
                     "text":"<sup>* </sup>Email:"
                  },
                  {
                     "text":"<sup>* </sup>Age:"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "roleOptionsLabel":"Which option best describes your current role?",
   "reccomendLabel":"<sup>* </sup>How likely is that you would recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?",
   "fccLabel":"What do you like most in FCC:",
   "improvedLabel":"Things that should be improved in the future(Check all that apply):",
   "commentsLabel":"Comments or Suggestions?"
};


$(document).ready(function(){
  var obj = json;
  divTitle(obj);
  divForm(obj);
});

function divTitle(obj){
  $('.form-title').text(obj.formTitle);
};
function divForm(obj){
  $('#paraf').text(obj.letUsnow);

  for(i in obj.info){
      for(j in obj.info[i].infoPersonalInfo){
          for(k in obj.info[i].infoPersonalInfo[j].infoLabel){
              $('.info-label-class').eq(k).html(obj.info[i].infoPersonalInfo[j].infoLabel[k].text);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="#" id="data-form">
    <div class="info">
        <div class="input-personal-info">
            <div class="info-label">
                <label class="info-label-class bla" for="name"> </label>
            </div>
            <div class="info-input">
                <input id="name" class="info-input-class" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-personal-info">
            <div class="info-label">
                <label class="info-label-class" for="email"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="info-input">
                <input id="email" class="info-input-class" type="email" name="Mail" placeholder="Enter your Email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-personal-info">
            <div class="info-label">
                <label class="info-label-class"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="info-input">
                <input class="info-input-class" type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow this worked ! Can you give me an explanation please ?

Comment: "k" contains the base 0 index of the JSON infoLabel object. Since you have 3 elements there, and 3 elements in the HTML, you can reuse that same index to retrieve the HTML element where you want the text to render. To do that, you target all the .info-label-class with jQuery, and then do a subfilter with eq. That will give you element that matches that index. Have a look at: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Ah i see. Thanks ! This helped a lot :)